# Working Efficiently with Hibernate Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

My code is working but my experience with spring is like 1 week old and I want to understand how things work, and how to make my code efficient as possible.

first example:
I have a group object in my database and each group has posts
@OneToMany

```
public List<Group> findAllGroups() {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Group.class);
    return (List<Group>) criteria.list();
}
```

this return a list with 160 of the same group because I have 160 posts related to this group, So I added :

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Is that really efficient? I mean doesn't it just gets the same list and just filters it?

How would I make it so it only does it once?

Second example:

I want to know how much posts each group has and I don't want to use group.findAllPosts().size(), What should I do about it?

It's very important for me to know this sort of stuff, Because you cant say "I can develop in Spring" while wasting so much resources.

Comment: Well, you can't really say "I can develop in Spring" after one week, or even after one month.

Comment: Well you can have 2 years experience with Spring or more.. and still code like ****. That's not the point, The point is I want to understand how and why things work the way they do.

Comment: It's good to want to understand. It's bad to say "I want you to make me understand". It's just too broad. Try to create specific questions.

Comment: I did.. those are my questions right now. how to make the above examples as efficient as possible

Comment: To understand, what it does, a good first step would be to look at the sql queries it produces/runs. There's a setting to enable the output for that, depending on how you configure it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distinct issue is not particularly inefficient (of course depending on your situation), at least in any well behaving database. Even if it were, it's not like you have a choice. Either you filter the results out yourself or you let the database and hibernate handle it (they do it better).

For the group sizes you need (or should use) aggregate functions. In SQL it would be something like `SELECT groupid, COUNT(*) FROM posts GROUP BY groupid`. HQL should have something quite similar, and the criteria API has `Projections` for it.

Comment: what do you mean by you don't have a choice? if I would manually send this query SELECT * FROM `groups` I would get exactly all the groups and not the duplicates caused by a post having a reference to a group. the question is how to do this in hibernate way? also Count will iterate over the posts, Could I add a column to each group saving the amount of posts and Update it with Hibernate each add/remove?

Comment: You could. But it would be a horrible idea. This has nothing to do with hibernate, etc.- just basic database design. If your database has a problem counting postings, then your database structure is simply bad and you should change that. Hibernate can do much, but it cannot magically fix a bad database structure.

Comment: @Anonymous Hibernate is actually executing `SELECT * FROM groups JOIN posts`, because it has a relation to posts. Are you interested in fetching entities or just the amount of entities, because those are completely different beasts. Full support to Florian's comment. If you don't know about database design, then trying to understand efficient Hibernate usage is completely impossible.

Comment: for example in my admin panel I want to see what groups I added so far, so I need them as individuals without relation to posts how can I do that with hibernate? (Select * from groups), my database is working very well, I am not asking because it doesn't work, in the near future each group could have hundreds of posts, so I want each request I issue to the database to be optimized as much as possible.

Comment: @Anonymous Then you probably want to aggregate the group names with the amount of posts like I showed in my answer (I'm not so fluent with the criteria API, so I can't write you the query off the top of my head). How good are you with creating complex queries in SQL? Because you'll need to know those before you can do the same with Hibernate. You should also understand your database engine very well, so you can be sure about things instead of guessing "this sounds slow". Hope you didn't think this would be easy and something you learn in a month.